# Tailwind CSS layout and css error in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I am creating of some website with Rails7, TailwindCSS is use as css framework. I have been changed layout and adding some components from [https://tailwindui.com/components](https://tailwindui.com/components/) , and then refresh the browser for changing the new design. But, it is not change directly. I stop starting server from the terminal, and then, I even take rails assets:precompile in terminal command. How to take auto changing for new design without precompile?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails#update-assets-automatically

Comment: How do you run the dev server? Make sure that there is the tailwind process watching for changes

Comment: I run with this command 'bin/dev'. I am not doing any changes.

Comment: This command line is add in Procfile 
`web: env RUBY_DEBUG_OPEN=true bin/rails server -p 3000
css: bin/rails tailwindcss:watch`

Comment: do not precompile in development. remove precompiled assets with `bin/rails assets:clobber` and then run `bin/dev`